# sorting by value in maps in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, dictionary, underscore.js

I have an object with many-to-one mapping:

```
{
  'a' : 'one',
  'b' : 'two',
  'c' : 'one',
  'd' : 'two'
}
```

Now I want to make the following object from this:

```
{
  'one' : ['a' , 'c'],
  'two' : ['b' , 'd']
}
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in javascript (we can also use underscore libraries if it helps)
Note: The above objects are just a shorter version of the actual problem.

Comment: what code have you written to solve the problem?

Comment: any attempt by yourself?

Comment: We can try to help your, but you have to try it first. Show us your first approach and then you will receive some suggestions, I'm sure of it.

Comment: Algo:  Iterate through object - create an empty array - if a new value of a key-val pair is encountered, store the value in the array - store the corresponding key as the value - if a value is already there, push the corresponding key to the list of values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with  [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var data = {'a': 'one','b': 'two','c': 'one','d': 'two'}

var result = Object.keys(data).reduce((res, e) => {
  res[data[e]] = (res[data[e]] || []).concat(e);
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

You could also use `forEach` and add to created object

```js
var data = {'a': 'one','b': 'two','c': 'one','d': 'two'}, r = {}

Object.keys(data).forEach(e => {r[data[e]] = (r[data[e]] || []).concat(e)});
console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = {
  'a' : 'one',
  'b' : 'two',
  'c' : 'one',
  'd' : 'two'
}

var result = {};

for(var key in data) {
    var val = data[key];
    if(!result[val]) result[val] = [];

    result[val].push(key);
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's my approach. Not as advanced as Nenad's though.

```
var obj = {
  'a' : 'one',
  'b' : 'two',
  'c' : 'one',
  'd' : 'two'
};

var result = {};

for (var i in obj) {
  if (obj[i] in result) {
    result[obj[i]].push(i);
  } else {
    result[obj[i]] = [i];
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I had also thought before

Answer (score 1):

a single liner

```js
var map = {
  'a' : 'one',
  'b' : 'two',
  'c' : 'one',
  'd' : 'two'
},

reduced = Object.keys(map).reduce((p,c) => {!!p[map[c]] ? p[map[c]].push(c) : p[map[c]] = [c]; return p},{})

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(reduced) + "</pre>");
```